# notation for minimum and maximum?

Tags: functions, notation, conditional-probability, machine-learning

I'm trying to figure out the correct notation for this situation for use in Machine Learning.

I have various ratings (for texts):

```
t1 ratings = +2, +3, +4
t2 ratnigs = -1, -2, +4
```

If when you multiply the minimum by the maximum of each vector you get a negative number, then the function output should be true. I guess each vector should be called y as they are the ratings for the Machine Learning.

This is as close as I have got, but I don't know if it's acceptable:
$$ 
f(y_t )=\min(y_t )\times\max(y_t )<0
$$

That is, for the vector or set of ratings y for a text t,the result should be TRUE if the minimum value in the set multiplied by the maximum value in the set is negative.

Comment: That looks fine.$$ 
f(y_t )=(\min(y_t ) \max(y_t )<0)
$$